# Adding new columns by looking into the column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie to pandas and python - Your answers are highly appreciated
I have a column in a data frame where it has values as follows: `df['columnname']`:

```
1 a:apple1 , b: banana1 , c: chocolate1 , d: dragonfruit1

2 a:apple2 , b: banana2 , c: chocolate2 , d: dragonfruit2

3 a:apple3 , b: banana3 , c: chocolate3 , d: dragonfruit3

4 a:apple4 , e: egg1 , b:banana4 , c: chocolate

5 a:apple5 , e: egg2 , b:banaa5 , c: chocolate5
```

I used `df.columnname.str.split(',',expand=true)`

I got the output as

```
0---1-------2----------3 -----------   4 
------------------------------------------------------------------
1 a:apple1  b: banana1  c: chocolate1  d: dragonfruit1

2 a:apple2  b: banana2  c: chocolate2  d: dragonfruit2

3 a:apple3  b: banana3  c: chocolate3  d: dragonfruit3

4 a:apple4  e: egg1     b:banana4      c: chocolate 

5 a:apple5  e: egg2     b:banaa5       c: chocolate5
```

My Expected output should be

```
0--1-------2----------  3--------      4     --------                  5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1 a:apple1  b: banana1  c: chocolate1  d: dragonfruit1                 0

2 a:apple2  b: banana2  c: chocolate2  d: dragonfruit2                 0

3 a:apple3  b: banana3  c: chocolate3  d: dragonfruit3                 0

4 a:apple4  b:banana4   c: chocolate4     0 or null                e: egg1    

5 a:apple5  b:banana5   c: chocolate5     0 or null                e: egg2
```

How can I rearrange the column values and arrange them to correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your strings look like dicts, one way of doing sort of what you want is to parse them to dicts and create a dataframe out of that:

```
list_of_dicts = [{x1.split(':')[0].strip():x1.split(':')[1].strip() for x1 in x.split(',')} for x in df['columnname']]
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_of_dicts)
```

|  | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple1 | banana1 | chocolate1 | dragonfruit1 | nan |
| 1 | apple2 | banana2 | chocolate2 | dragonfruit2 | nan |
| 2 | apple3 | banana3 | chocolate3 | dragonfruit3 | nan |
| 3 | apple4 | banana4 | chocolate | nan | egg1 |
| 4 | apple5 | banaa5 | chocolate5 | nan | egg2 |

Comment: Thank you very much